# Android 5.1.1 (CyanogenMod CM12.1) - problem Multimedia - pls HELP

Tags: cyanogenmod, media-player, video-streaming

I have an Alcatel One Touch Pop C7 (7041X) that is still a phone, but with too old software - Android 4.0.2, which not allow install of most the apps who I have interested.
I decided to upgrade it to the above level.
My goal was to achieve optimum functionality of device and durability of the battery.
I tried a lot of variants. Тhe most appealing to me stayed the version CyanogenMod CM12.1_StableEdition_V2.

[image]

This customROM (Android 5.1.1 (LolliPop)) is perfect in every way except the Multimedia. In my opinion the problem comes from the used decoders and encoders ... or more precisely in their settings ...I read on the Internet and maked a lot of experiments ... but alas with no result ...!
Now will be glad if I eliminate this problem with your help ...!
One quick word about the problem or at least what the most annoys me.
The problem appears when I try to watch TV online with the Da Player app (play streaming video in format *.m3u8). The application itself installs normally, loading the playlist also works, but when playing whoever it is channel, it previews the following (see attachment screen ) without sound.

[image: screen image]

I want to emphasize that on the same phone, but installed Android 4.4.2 (KitKat) - this effect is not observed - the app (Da Player) works fine.

The phone is rotatable and has an MT6582 processor.

I would be really glad if anybody would cooperate ...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You might have better luck at XDA with this question.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/alcatel-pop-c7/help/alcatel-onetouch-pop-c7-android-5-1-1-t4062761

....No...! I not have result....